# Get reference to jar assembly path in sbt

Tags: sbt

I'm using [sbt-izpack](http://software.clapper.org/sbt-izpack/) to build an installer. It looks like there's a [bug](https://github.com/bmc/sbt-izpack/issues/19) where the variable for the package file name isn't being referenced properly. I'm looking to [pass in a variable](http://software.clapper.org/sbt-izpack/#settings) so that the main jar is properly packaged like so:

```
variables in IzPack += ("artifactName", artifactFileName.value )
```

The thing is I can't figure out how to get a path string of the main artifact. The [docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Artifacts.html#Modifying+default+artifacts) say that I can map over package and get a `(Artifact, File)` pair like so:

```
val artifactFileName = settingKey[String]("My task.")

artifactFileName :=  {
  val (art, file) = packagedArtifact.in(Compile, packageBin).value
  println("Artifact definition: " + art)
  println("Packaged file: " + file.getAbsolutePath)
  file.getAbsolutePath
}
```

But sbt complains that `A setting cannot depend on a task`.

Is there a way that I can somehow get the path of the main assembly without needing to generate it first (in a task) so that I can pass it in via a setting?

Alternatively, is there someway to update the setting supplied to izpack in a task?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like the answer is in the documentation, but it's not obvious because it's in the section about modifying artifacts, not reading their properties.

From: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Detailed-Topics/Artifacts.html#modifying-default-artifacts:

> Each built-in artifact has several configurable settings in addition to publish-artifact. The basic ones are `artifact` (of type `SettingKey[Artifact]`), `mappings` (of type `TaskKey[(File,String)]`), and `artifactPath` (of type `SettingKey[File]`). They are scoped by (`<config>`, `<task>`) as indicated in the previous section.

So you can get the string value of the artifactPath, which is a setting and thereby usable in the izPack setting, with the following:

```
lazy val artifactPathExt = settingKey[String]("Get the main artifact path")
artifactPathExt := (artifactPath in (Compile, packageBin)).value.getPath
```

---

While I forget exactly how I happened across this, here's how one might discover this information (discoverability in sbt being somewhat of a problem):

One knows that the `package` task builds the main output, so you can type:

```
inspect tree package
```

At the sbt prompt, which displays the following tree:

```
> inspect tree package
[info] compile:package = Task[java.io.File]
[info]   +-compile:packageBin = Task[java.io.File]
[info]     +-compile:packageBin::packageConfiguration = Task[sbt.Package$Conf..
[info]     | +-compile:packageBin::artifactPath = target\scala-2.11\scaladaem..
[info]     | | +-*:scalaBinaryVersion = 2.11
[info]     | | +-*:scalaVersion = 2.11.5
```

Here you can see that the `package` task requires `compile:packageBin::packageConfiguration`.  You can inspect the value of this setting at the sbt prompt.

To actually grab a hold of this value in your build, you'd have to know about how to reference this thing.  You'd have to figure out Keys, Tasks and [Scopes](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/tutorial/Scopes.html).  You'd have to know the "in" syntax of getting keys out of [configs and tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Task-Inputs.html).  Finally, you'd have to know how to [declare and use custom tasks](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.2/docs/Getting-Started/Custom-Settings.html) and the how settings and tasks are referenced and declared at runtime.  Finally, you'd have to know how use a setting to set another setting.

Whew.

Comment: This issue is still present in sbt-izpack and your solution works great. Thanks!